# Выключение виртуализации в TabControl (Avalonia 11)

Tags: c#, xaml, avalonia

При переключении на другие вкладки, `TabControl` не хранит их состояния (скроллбары, октрытые узлы `TreeView`, выбранные элементы и т.д.), в этом и суть виртуализации, конечно, но мне она не нужна. В старых версиях авалонии (до 0.11) были удобные свойства `VirtualMode` и `IsVirtualized` для включения\отключения виртуализации у контейнеров. Сейчас же относительно просто виртуализацию включить (`VirtualizedStackPanel`), но совершенно не понятно как ее выключить.

Comment: Хм, а при чем тут виртуализация? Если вы грамотно размещаете данные, используете привязки, то у вас такого просто быть не может, ибо все важные состояния у вас в простых классах, а не в контролах (UI). Так что, тут не на виртуализацию смотреть надо, а на то, как данные попадают в UI.

Comment: `в этом и суть виртуализации, конечно` нет, не в этом. У вас ваши VM или модели видимо пересоздаются при переключении.

Comment: У меня подобная проблема, данные сохраняются в памяти, а визуально условно тоже самое `TreeView` оно просто свернулось и приходится заново открывать ее. Я думаю условный фокус элемента должен исправить эту проблему, тк если заходить на форму и сразу фокус на выбранный элемент `TreeView` будет падать то она откроется

Comment: В конструкторе ViewModel главного окна я создаю экземпляры дочерних вьюмоделей, далее обращаюсь к ним уже через свойства. То есть создаются они единожды, я их не пересоздаю нигде. А вот табы содержат в себе UserControl, которому присвоена ссылка на вьюмодель нужного таба.

Comment: На счет TreeView решение нашел неожиданно: искал как сделать Expand, наткнулся на ответ [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73052955/reactivecommand-when-treeview-is-expanded]. А т.к. структура древа теперь имеет состояние IsExpanded, то переключение вкладки не меняет его. Вопрос можно закрывать